# Creating a static IP address for an highly secured Raspberry router to navigate anonymously

Tags: networking, static-ip

I want to transform my Raspberry Pi as an highly secured router to navigate anonymously wherever I would be thanks to Onion Pi. (Actually I'm doing some tutorials in order to have a better understanding of Raspberry, networking and addresses.)
**Yet, I wasn't able to give to my Raspberry a static IP address.** Indeed, after having followed the following steps:

- SSH connexion to my Raspberry Pi: ssh [user]@[IP address]
- installed the Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol sudo get-apt
  install hstapd isc-dhcp-server
- configured DHCP by adding a # to the two options about domain name
  a,d suppressing # in front of the authoritative option seven lines
  under
- adding

  ```
  subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
      range 192.168.42.10 192.168.42.50;
      option broadcast-adress 192.168.42.255;
      option routers 192.168.42.1;
      default-lease-time 600;
      max-lease-time 7200;
      option domain-name "local";
      option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8,
      8.8.4.4;
  }
  ```

to the file and saving it,

- modified the DHCP server settings in order to be able to use it with
  a wireless adaptor: `Interfaces ="wlan0"`
- set the Wifi adaptator with a static address an enabling it to receive incoming signals `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` adding a `#` to `iface wlan 0` and to the following lines abiut anything connectod to `wlan0`
- Finally give to the interface a static IP address:

  ```
  iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.XX.X
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  ```

saving.

- When I try to assign the wlan0 address 192.168.XX.X it answers me:

  ```
  :~ $ sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.XX.X
  SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
  wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
  ```

### Debugging attempt

Therefore, I tried to debug trying to get the networks around me but it told me that the interface doesn't support scanning

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Comment: It looks like your issue is more than just being unable to assign an address -- it's saying there is **No such device** to assign the address too.  Edit in the output from `ip link`.  I've edited your question to correct the display of "preformatted text" such as from a console, file, code, etc.  Please see [the formatting help page](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: (An unfortunate PITA not mentioned in that help page is that if you include "preformatted text" in a list item, you must indent it a further four spaces, and the `{ }` button isn't smart enough to get that.)

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you for editing my question. So, what should I do to find the devices that should receive the address?